# Symfony3 ignores validation.yml for form children

Tags: validation, symfony

I have no idea what happened because it used to work and now all of a sudden it does not.

So let's start with `Controller`:

```
        $user = new User();
        $studio = new Studio();
        $transformer = new StudioAccountDataTransformer($user, $studio);
        $form = $this->createForm(StudioAccountForm::class, $transformer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
             // isValid always true
        }
```

and now the `StudioAccountForm`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', UserType::class, [
            'label' => false
        ])
        ->add('studio', StudioType::class, [
            'label' => false
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain'    => 'general',
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\DataTransformer\StudioAccountDataTransformer',
        'attr'                  => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        'cascade_validation'    => true,
        'validation_groups'     => ['Default', 'admin']
    ]);
}
```

and `UserType` (StudioType looks similar, nothing special)

```
use FirstNameField;
use LastNameField;
use EmailAddressField;
use SexField;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option)
{
    $this->firstName($builder);
    $this->lastName($builder);
    $this->emailAddress($builder);
    $this->sex($builder);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain'    => 'general',
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        'attr'                  => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        'csrf_protection'       => false,
        'studio'                => null,
        'expanded'              => false
    ]);
}
```

`StudioAccountDataTransformer` is just getters/setters for `studio` and `user`.
So here's the `validation.yml`

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: [api, admin]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 255
                groups: [api, admin]
        lastName:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: [api, admin]
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 255
                groups: [api, admin]
```

and in the `config.yml` I have

```
validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

As you can see `StudioAccountForm` has two other forms included `UserType` and `StudioType` and I should get errors from `UserType` since `validation_groups` is configured properly. Moreover, there's also `cascade_validation` enabled. Somehow validation does not work this way (I am pretty sure it was working).

*Note*: If I put just `UserType` in `Controller`'s createForm() function then valiation works. So obviously `.yml` file is loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And finally I got it.

So from Symfony 2.8 log

```
The "cascade_validation" option was deprecated. Use the "constraints"
   option together with the `Valid` constraint instead. Contrary to
   "cascade_validation", "constraints" must be set on the respective child forms,
   not the parent form.
```

So instead of using `cascade_validation` I should use `Valid` constraint, as in example below

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', UserType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Valid()
            ]
        ])
        ->add('studio', StudioType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new Valid()
            ]
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'translation_domain'    => 'general',
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\DataTransformer\StudioAccountDataTransformer',
        'attr'                  => ['novalidate' => 'novalidate'],
        'validation_groups'     => ['Default', 'admin']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I'm facing the same issue and your answer saved me :)